# Xcode project build: Failed

Tags: ios, xcode, header-files, build-error

I'm working on simple app, and there is no errors while i'm writing the code, but when i push build button, the error has occur. Build myProject: Failed, and xCode show me two error warnings. Here the errors message:

```
 Ld /Users/MacUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-azorstixlscpikfhurtxwvvwachh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Calculator.app/Calculator normal i386
cd "/Users/MacUser/Downloads/Downloads/Desktop/old drop box/calc/Calculator"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
-L/Users/MacUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-azorstixlscpikfhurtxwvvwachh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator 
-F/Users/MacUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-azorstixlscpikfhurtxwvvwachh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator 
-filelist /Users/MacUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-azorstixlscpikfhurtxwvvwachh/Build/Intermediates/Calculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Calculator.build/Objects-normal/i386/Calculator.LinkFileList 
-mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker 
-objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 
-fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 
-framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics 
-o /Users/MacUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Calculator-azorstixlscpikfhurtxwvvwachh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Calculator.app/Calculator

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AxesDrawer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AxesView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am found something, here is my controller.m code:

```
#import "AxesView.h"
#import "AxesDrawer.h"

@implementation AxesView


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   CGRect b;
   b = self.bounds;
   CGPoint aO;
   aO = b.origin;
   CGFloat pPU;
   pPU = b.size.height;

   [AxesDrawer drawAxesInRect:(CGRect)b originAtPoint:(CGPoint)aO scale:(CGFloat)pPU];
}
@end
```

The problem i think in my AxesDrawer.h file, but i don't know why. If i change import from AxesDrawer.h to AxesDrawer.m (i know that's wrong but just for test)
the project will build and work in simulator. Can somebody help me with this? What i made wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AxesDrawer.m is probably not in your target. Click on it and use the far-right Utilities panel and make sure it's checked for the target you're building.